# SQL Server Index Usage with an Order By

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table named Workflow. There are 38M rows in the table. There is a PK on the following columns:

```
ID: Identity Int
ReadTime: dateTime
```

If I perform the following query, the PK is not used. The query plan shows an index scan being performed on one of the nonclustered indexes plus a sort. It takes a very long time with 38M rows.

```
Select TOP 100 ID From Workflow
Where ID > 1000
Order By ID
```

However, if I perform this query, a nonclustered index (on LastModifiedTime) is used. The query plan shows an index seek being performed. The query is very fast.

```
Select TOP 100 * From Workflow
Where LastModifiedTime > '6/12/2010'
Order By LastModifiedTime
```

So, my question is this. Why isn't the PK used in the first query, but the nonclustered index in the second query is used?

Comment: What order are the columns in the PK defined? ID then ReadTime? Could be your data is ordered in ReadTime order instead of ID then ReadTime.

Comment: You may have to rebuild your index.  Also, you can force it to use the index. Lastly, you shouldn't have a datetime part of an index if you can avoid it, the index will corrupt  - I suspect because it's really a float.

Comment: @Mark Perry - Yes, ID + ReadTime

Comment: @GBN - The number of rows that should be returned is 100 (see TOP 100)

Comment: Sorry, I meant how many rows satisfy the WHERE without TOP?

Comment: @GBN - Then you were right, 37,999,900, at least.

Comment: Can you post the script that creates the table, including all indexes?

Comment: And for the LastModifiedTime query?

Comment: @gbn - Roughly 20M on the LastModifiedTime query.

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to fish around in your database, there are a few things that come to my mind.

- Are you certain that the PK is `(id, ReadTime)` as opposed to `(ReadTime, id)`?
- What execution plan does `SELECT MAX(id) FROM WorkFlow` yield?
- What about if you create an index on `(id, ReadTime)` and then retry the test, or your query?

Answer (score 2):

Since Id is an identity column, having ReadTime participate in the index is superfluous.  The clustered key already points to the leaf data.  I recommended you modify your indexes

```
CREATE TABLE Workflow
(
  Id       int IDENTITY,
  ReadTime datetime,
  -- ... other columns, 
  CONSTRAINT PK_WorkFlow
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
  (
    Id
  ) 

)

CREATE INDEX idx_LastModifiedTime
ON WorkFlow
(
  LastModifiedTime
)
```

Also, check that statistics are up to date.

Finally, If there are 38 million rows in this table, then the optimizer may conclude that specifying criteria > 1000 on a unique column is non selective, because > 99.997% of the Ids are > 1000  (if your identity seed started at 1).   In order for an index to considered helpful, the optimizer must conclude that < 5% of the records would be selected.  You can use an index hint to force the issue (as already stated by Dan Andrews).  What is the structure of the non-clustered index that was scanned?

Comment: +1 for seek vs scan based on selectivity of the `WHERE` clause.